# Increasing the size of a vector in for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

If i increase the size of a `std::vector` in a `for` loop when it is a parameter of the `for` loop, will it work? Will the `for` loop recalculate the size of the vector on each iteration?

Example:

```
for(int i=0; i<myVector.size(); i++)
{
   myVector.push_back(new element);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should be aware that modifying the vector invalidates iterators. That can cause trouble if you iterate over the vector in the loop, e.g. do `for(auto x: some_vector) { some_vector.push_back(new_element);}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `myVector.size()` will be re-evaluated on each iteration, returning a larger value each time. Therefore, your loop would never end, because it would be like a dog chasing its own tail (assuming that the initial size is non-zero).

If you would like to double the number of elements in the vector, you need to store `myVector.size()` upfront, and use the stored value in your loop, like this:

```
size_t origSize = myVector.size();
for(int i=0; i<origSize; i++)
{
   myVector.push_back(new element);
}
```

Comment: Yes, with the above code example, it would be an infinite loop. That's just a generalization of a concept. In my actual code, i have a limited number of new elements that get added, but i need to loop based on the updated size of the vector. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in a for loop is recalculated each iteration. So that example code will never terminate as the size will keep recalculating and `i` will never catch up.